# How to find a "quadrilateral" grid that matches a set of points in 2D?

Tags: python, algorithm, mesh

Given a set of n*m distinct points in 2D space with an arbitrary distribution. This is an abstract algorithm problem, where the points could be anywhere.

[image]

How to match these points to a "quadrilateral" grid of n*m coordinates, such that

1. each datapoint has exactly one coordinate
2. no two datapoints have the same coordinate
3. the rectangular grid is "flat", ie no intersections of the connecting lines of neighbouring coordinates?
4. The n * m grid of quads corresponds to a rectangular grid of dimensions n * m

[image]

Example for the 4th condition with n = 2 and m = 3. The first grid is not a solution, as the grid is not of the type 2x3 (it is of type 1x6):
[image]

In my real world case I have a few thousand datapoints.

It seems to me that this problem should occur regularly, however, I was not able to find an algorithm that solves this problem.

It was pointed out in the comments that there may be degenerate cases where many points lie all on exactly the same line. I would not mind if the datapoints are moved a tiny bit to avoid those degenerated cases - as long their distance relationship is not really distorted.

I tried to apply a SOM (Self Organizing Map), but this leaves empty spots in the grid and maps different datapoints on the same grid-point.
I also tried to iteratively apply a Quantiletransformer, but this will require some complicated divide and conquer scheme, and even then I am not sure if it will work out.
I thought maybe an algorithm based on "masses and springs" could be applied, but I have not tried this.

Comment: Is anything known about the distribution of the points? Are you trying to match a real grid in a photo, or is this an abstract algorithm problem where the points could be anywhere? Is it guaranteed that there is a solution?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried researched so far? Share your ideas / findings / code.

Comment: I suggest substituting "quadrilateral" for "rectangle" in your question. Right now the only thing that makes the question understandable is the image for the example solution.

Comment: You could draw inspiration from the question [numpy - Create triangular mesh from vertex coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614478/create-triangular-mesh-from-vertex-coordinates), noting that two adjacent triangles form one quadrilateral.

Comment: There obviously is a degenerate case with all arbitrarily placed points in the same spot or on a line. That means there are likely also lots of degenerate cases where one edge of the grid cannot be placed properly. Is that an issue?

Comment: *"I tried to apply a SOM"* What is a SOM?

Comment: @Stef In mesh context, the cells are actually called _quadrilaterals_ or _quads_. What sets them apart from rect-angles is that the angles are not 90 degrees.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer ...Yes?

Answer (score 0):

The typical approach here would be to construct a triangular grid, and then merge the triangles into quads. However, it is impossible to reconstruct meshes from point clouds only. What *is* possible is to create a mesh of the convex hull of the point set; see [scipy.spatial.Delaunay](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think this will lead to an arbitrary mesh of quads. However I am looking to find a n * m grid of quads. I added a picture in the description to make this condition more clear.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for constructing a grid is to take the bottom 3 points, sort them by their x-values, take the next 3, and so forth. Note that might give you different results depending on the rotation of the point cloud.

[image]